# 今からプログラミング始めるのですが何から始めたらいいですか

Tags: プログラミング言語

webのプログラミングとか、パソコンを動かすためのプログラミングとか、学ぼうと思ってズルズル引きずって来たので、何から始めたらいいですか？
パソコンはfujitsuのintelのOS?はWindowsです
高校生で商業科に通っています
パソコンで使ったことがあるソフトウェアは、
エクセルとワードくらいです

#### 追記

- 全体的にネットを動かしたい
- webに関しては、あまりぱっとするイメージがありません
- OS作ってみたいです！

Comment: プログラミングの可能性は大きいのですが、何を実現したいのか曖昧すぎて回答は付けづらいと思います。

Comment: 何を実現…？webのプログラミングとか…パソコンをプログラミングで作るとか…

Comment: プログラミングすることが目的ということですか？それこそ範囲が広すぎます。言語を絞るなり質問に工夫が必要です。

Comment: webのプログラミングというのは、自己紹介サイトなどのホームページを作ってみたいということですか？　それとも、ブラウザで実行できる電卓などのような、webアプリを作ってみたいということでしょうか。

Comment: パソコンを作ってみたいというのは、OSを作ってみたいということでしょうか。OSというのは、WindowsやMac OSなどの、コンピュータのソフトウェアを支えている基本ソフトウェアのことです。それとも、コンピュータの上で動くアプリを何か作ってみたいということでしょうか？

Comment: htbさん、その言語を何から始めたらいいのかなー？って事です！

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、全体的にネットを動かしたいです

Comment: webに関しては、あまりぱっとするイメージがありません

Comment: nekketsuuuさん.基本ソフトウェア作ってみたいです！そんな感じで何から始めればいいのかなぁって…

Comment: このサイトで質問とするトピックを理解できるまで読んで下さい。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: 「主観的な答えしか集まらない」としてクローズ票を投じます．このような質問をしたくなること自体は理解できますが，このサイトに適した具体的で客観的な回答が存在するとは予期できないと思います．一番「答え」に近いのは「なんでもいいから始めるのがよい」というところではないでしょうか．まずOSを作るところに最短で到達したい（なら多分C）とか，まずブラウザ上でものを動かしてみたい（ならほぼ JavaScript 一択）というような，それでググれば特定の言語が出てくるような現時点での単独の目的がないなら，最初の選択は信頼できる友人や先生のおすすめ・図書館に本が充実してる・よいうわさをよく聞く・なんとなくとかそういうのでいいと思います．例えばPython, C, C++, JavaScript, lisp あたりは挙がりやすいでしょうが．

Comment: んー、頭の固い人たちばかりだなぁ

Comment: 何も知らない初心者の人に

Comment: プログラミングを始める上で何から始めたらいいのか、どのサイトを活用するか、どういった行動を踏まえてから取り掛かるか、などの情報を求めているのに…

Comment: 他の方のコメントにもありますが、初学者がよい学習法を求めるのは当然の事ですし、それを誰かしらに質問するのも、非難される事ではありません。
この質問が「改善待ち」や「クローズ」という扱いになっても、それが示すのは「このサイトにおいては、この種の話題は扱わない」という事だけです。
これに懲りず、プログラミングを始めて下さい。
（何事もそうかも知れませんが、プログラミングには面倒だったり、カオスであったりする面があります。学習を進めるにつれ、何か「プログラミング完全マスターへの最短距離」のような物があるのだけれど、自分がそれを知らないだけなのではないか、という不安が生じるかも知れませんが、心配しないで下さい。そういった物はありません）

Comment: 誰もがそうであったように何も知らなくたってウェルカムなんですが、サイトのルールだけは知っておいて下さい。

Comment: 回答は書けませんが、アドバイスするなら考える前に始めちゃったほうがいいです。「java入門」でググって書いてあるサイトを上から順番に読んで、書かれてることを実際に試してみてください。

Comment: 皆さんありがとうございます！とりあえず調べて頑張ってみます

Answer (score 5):

(OSを作りたい、という前提のもとで回答します)

オペレーティングシステム (OS) を作るためや、ネットワークのとても基礎的な部分をさわるためのプログラミング言語として古くから使われているのは、C言語のみでしょう。
正直はじめてのプログラミング言語としてはとっつきにくいですが、他を思いつきません。

C言語を学ぶためのWeb上にある無料の日本語資料としては、たとえば[『苦しんで覚えるC言語』](http://9cguide.appspot.com/)があります。
これが気に入らなければ、[『一週間で身につくC言語の基本』](http://c-lang.sevendays-study.com/)などの他のサイトや[書店で売っている書籍](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/?field-keywords=C%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E)、あるいは[ドット・インストールのC言語入門](http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_c)などの動画教材が参考になるでしょう。

C言語をある程度読み書きできるようになったら、次のステップです。
OSを作るための基礎を学べる日本語の書籍としては[『30日でできる! OS自作入門』](https://www.amazon.co.jp/30%E6%97%A5%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B-OS%E8%87%AA%E4%BD%9C%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80-%E5%B7%9D%E5%90%88-%E7%A7%80%E5%AE%9F/dp/4839919844)がおすすめです。
OSを作る中で、コンピュータでたくさんのアプリケーションを同時に動かしたり、メモリを管理したり、TCP/IPをはじめとするネットワークの処理をしたりなどするためにはどういうことが必要なのかということが学べることでしょう。
この本が気に入らなければ、類書として[『12ステップで作る組込みOS自作入門』](https://www.amazon.co.jp/12%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B%E7%B5%84%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BFOS%E8%87%AA%E4%BD%9C%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80-%E5%9D%82%E4%BA%95-%E5%BC%98%E4%BA%AE/dp/4877832394)があります（ただし組み込みOSという分野なので普段使っているWindowsやmacOSとは少し異なるOSになります）。また、[「Linuxカーネル」で検索したら見つかる本](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s/field-keywords=Linux%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB)も、少し難しいですが参考になるかもしれません。

全体的に難しいことだらけだとは思いますので、自分で考えるだけでは解決しないことが多々あると思います。そういった場合はまず色んな単語で検索してみましょう。それでも駄目だった場合は再びスタック・オーバーフローのような質問サイトを利用したり、詳しい知人に尋ねたりするのが良いと思います。

---

[おまけ]

ここから更に深く知りたい場合、少し毛色は違いますがIPA (情報処理推進機構) が主催するセキュリティ・キャンプの全国大会や地方大会でたまに開かれているOSにまつわる講座を見に行くと面白いでしょう。

- [セキュリティ・キャンプ実施協議会](http://www.security-camp.org/index.html)
- [セキュリティ・キャンプ 全国大会 2014 セキュアなシステムを作ろうクラス](http://www.ipa.go.jp/jinzai/camp/2014/zenkoku2014_kougi.html#section6)
- [セキュリティ・キャンプ九州 in 福岡 2016 いじって壊して遊んでハッカーになろう](http://www.security-camp.org/minicamp/kyushu2016.html)
- [セキュリティ・キャンプ 全国大会 2017 言語やOSを自作しよう](https://www.ipa.go.jp/jinzai/camp/2017/zenkoku2017_kougi.html#section7)

あるいは、実際のOSのソースコードを眺めてみるのも面白いかもしれません。たとえばLinuxというOSの中心部分 (OSカーネル) のソースコードはここで見れます。

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux

[xv6](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv6)や[Minix](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minix)などの教育用の小さいOSからはじめ、カーネルハックして遊ぶのも面白いかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！参考になります